# Determining if __init__() is called as a result of method call

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a case where, evidently, `__init__()` is called as a result of a method call.  (Not precisely sure why; suspect it may have to do with needing to return a copy.)

Example of the class's design:

```
import copy
import pandas as pd

class TSeries(pd.Series):
    # See:
    # https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html

    _metadata = ['some_new_attr']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Copy needed because we would otherwise inadvertantly alter
        # mutable arguments such as pd.Series, TSeries, etc.
        args = tuple(copy.deepcopy(arg) for arg in args)
        some_new_attr = kwargs.pop('some_new_attr', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('WE ARE "IN IT."')

        # Put a calculation here that that we *don't* want to call
        # if class instance is instantiated as a result of
        # of self.new_method().
        #
        # _do_some_conditional_calculation(self)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        # Used when a manipulation result has the same
        # dimesions as the original.  Fairly sure
        # self.new_method() uses this.
        return TSeries

    def new_method(self):
        return self * 100
```

Calling a method, as a result of which `__init__()` is called:

```
>>> x = TSeries([1, 2, 3])
WE ARE "IN IT."

>>> x.new_method()
WE ARE "IN IT."      # <-- __init__() called
0    100
1    200
2    300
dtype: int64
```

My desire is to do some inplace operation on `self` within `__init__()`, but *not* if the call occurred because of a method call.  (Or, more directly, "do the operation only if the user instantiates an instance of `TSeries` directly.")

How can I differentiate between these two cases?

---

Update - this illustrates what I'm trying to do, but seems dangerous.

```
IS_METHOD_CALL = False


class TSeries(pd.Series):
    # See:
    # https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html

    _metadata = ['some_new_attr']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Copy needed because we would otherwise inadvertantly alter
        # mutable arguments such as pd.Series, TSeries, etc.
        args = tuple(copy.deepcopy(arg) for arg in args)
        some_new_attr = kwargs.pop('some_new_attr', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print('WE ARE "IN IT."')

        # Put a calculation here that that we *don't* want to call
        # if class instance is instantiated as a result of
        # of self.new_method().

        global IS_METHOD_CALL
        if not IS_METHOD_CALL:
            print('Some conditional calculation')
        IS_METHOD_CALL = False

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        # Used when a manipulation result has the same
        # dimesions as the original.  Fairly sure
        # self.new_method() uses this.
        return TSeries

    def new_method(self):
        # We'd need to do within every single method...
        global IS_METHOD_CALL
        IS_METHOD_CALL = True
        return self * 100
```

Conditional calc is skipped:

```
>>> x = TSeries([1, 2, 3])
WE ARE "IN IT."
Some conditional calculation

>>> x.new_method()
WE ARE "IN IT."
0    100
1    200
2    300
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Removing my previous comment; even way down deep, any new object is still being called via `cls(...)`, where `cls` is any reference (no more or less special than `TSeries` itself) to the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to explicitly tell `TSeries.__init__` to perform the conditional calculation. There's nothing the really distinguishes between explicit and implicit calls to `TSeries.__new__` (via `type.__call__(TSeries, ...)`).

```
class TSeries(pd.Series):
    def __init__(self, ..., extra_config=False):
        ...
        if extra_config:
            self._do_some_conditional_calculation()
```

Now, the only way to execute `_do_some_conditional_calculation` is to request it explicitly: `x = TSeries([1,2,3], extra_config=True)`.

Comment: Hm, I'm surprised by this, frankly.  As luck would have it, I need `extra_config=True` as the default.  (i.e. implicitly False when `__init__` is called from methods.)

Comment: The problem is that `TSeries` isn't special in terms of Python's execution model. `TSeries` is a name bound to an object of type `type`. As such, `TSeries(...)` is just syntactic sugar for `type(TSeries).__call__(...)`, and the implementation of `type.__call__` is to call `object.__new__(TSeries, ...)` and return whatever it returns. That means it doesn't matter what reference is used to start the process; it's all the same eventually.

Comment: Updated my question ... if you have a second, curious if you think proposed solution is an awful idea.

Comment: Ah, it looks like you are assuming that you'll only ever make one instance of the class. Why not have `new_method` mutate the existing object instead of  creating a new one? There's probably a deeper design question here, including the question of whether you should use composition instead of inheritance to define `TSeries`.